# How Spring - server.connection-timeout will work internally?

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, tomcat, connection-timeout

I'm little confused on how the server.connection-timeout property will work on a spring boot REST API project

I have a Spring boot REST API Project in which I have a delete REST API, this will basically do couple of delete operation on a Database table say for example this delete API will delete some rows on 3 tables as following

Delete API gets "customer Id" as Input and execution the following

1. Delete all records matching the customer Id in Table A (delete call to an external DB)
2. Delete all records matching the customer Id in Table B (delete call to an external DB)
3. Delete all records matching the customer Id in Table C (delete call to an external DB)

my question here is if I set "server.connection-timeout" to 5 Seconds what does it actually means?

I have 2 two assumptions

1. The delete Rest Api will timeout in 5 Seconds meaning all the 3 external DB call has to be done within the 5 Seconds if not the REST API will timeout
2. Each external DB call will have 5 Seconds timeout, in this case 15 Seconds totally

In worst case if all the 3 External DB call takes 4 Seconds then the Delete API will take 12 Seconds to respond - is this a valid one?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing. **server.connection-timeout** – is the time that connectors wait for another HTTP request before closing the connection.

It doesn't matter how much time it takes to complete the request.
In your case if server.connection-timeout is 5, this will not effect #1 #2 or #3 deletes which you mentioned.

In a simple terms connection-timeout does not apply to long running requests. Instead It applies to the initial connection, when the server waits for the client to request something.

**Default:** the connector’s container-specific default is used. Use a value of -1 to indicate infinite timeout.

Comment: Is there a way to set specifc timeout for one of the controller? I mean this server.connection-timeout should be applicable for all the endpoints and I need to specify the a new timeout for a particular endpoint